# How to loop back from "z" to "a" in the alphabet in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, modulo, caesar-cipher

Let me start off by saying I'm just learning Java. I'm having an issue looping back from the letter "z" to "a".

```
System.out.println("You chose Decryption!");
br.nextLine();

System.out.println("Type a message:");
String msg = br.nextLine();

String decryptedMessage = "";

for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++){
    int decryption = msg.charAt(i);

    //Trying to loop back from "a" to "z"
    decryption = ((char)decryption % 26);
    decryptedMessage = decryptedMessage + ((char) (decryption - 1));

}

System.out.println(decryptedMessage);
```

I used the modulo operation `decryption = ((char)decryption % 26);` but instead of the letter "a", the code is giving me a bracket ([). Why isn't this working?

Comment: try a `for` loop `'z'` to `'a'` ... notice the single quotes

Comment: Note that `'a' - 'a' = 0` and `'b' - 'a' = 1` and so on.

Comment: That first comment is incorrect @jsotola, the loop goes through the message, not the alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what is the real problem. The code looks like a Caesar cipher problem, but you are asking for looping back form z to a. if you remove the line

```
decryption = ((char)decryption % 26);
```

You'll get closer to decripting the message, because I think is that you choose a shift=1 to encrypt your messages.
I'm guessing you are asking for looping form z to a because of the [caesar cipher definition in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

If my guess is correct the problem is that the number representation of char is not 'a'=0, 'b'=1 and so on, but 'A' has a numeric representation of 65 and 'a' of 97. You are shifting a wrong number.

Answer (score 3):

Acccroding to [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) char 'a' is equale to 97 (DEC) as mentioned above.
I highly recommend you look through this table. It will help you to understand what's going on under hood.
So then your write `'a'+1` in fact it is conver to 97 + 1.